# Flask optional upload file

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I have a form that contains several text fields and one file field:

```
class PictureForm(Form):

    title = StringField(u'Title',validators=[Required()])
    description = TextAreaField(u'Description')
    gallery = QuerySelectField(u'Which 
        gallery?',query_factory=all_galleries,validators=[Required()])
    imagekind = StringField(u'Imagekind URL')
    pic = FileField('Image upload')

    submit = SubmitField(u'Upload/edit picture')
```

What I am trying to have is a view for editing images that may or may not accept a new image. If there is a file in request.files I want to use it and replace the old image. However if there is not a file, I want the view to just update the metadata (the name, the gallery, the imagekind link etc) whilst leaving the old imagefile.

The view looks like this:

```
@main.route('/picture/edit/<id>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit_picture(id):

    # old picture
    picture = Picture.query.get_or_404(id)

    # form data - old picture
    form = PictureForm(obj=picture)

    if form.validate_on_submit():

        #  update picture data
        picture.title = form.title.data
        picture.description = form.description.data
        picture.gallery = form.gallery.data
        picture.imagekind = form.imagekind.data

        # new image if uploaded
        image = request.files['pic']
        filename = ''

        if image:

            # replace old file on disk with new image...
            # some PIL processing

            # new file names

        else:

            msg = u'No new image, just updated the metadata'
            flash(msg,'warning')

        db.session.add(picture)
        db.session.commit()

        return redirect(url_for('main.admin_page'))     

    return render_template('main/new_picture.html', form = form, edit=True, 
        picture = picture)
```

When the form is given a file/picture, everything works as it should. However, when I try without an image or file in the form, I get a 400 Bad request? Any ideas? All of the fields have the proper ids and names...

Answer (score 1):

Stupid mistake: I had to check with:

```
if 'pic' in request.files:
```

and then take it from there.